# SignalR occurs error [Invalid frame header] when use webpack dev server proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, signalr, webpack-dev-server

SignalR occurs error [Invalid frame header] when use webpack dev server proxy

Win10 + NodeJs(10.15.3)

There is a web frontend project use `@aspnet/signalr` module, and develop with `webpack-dev-server`.

I use `@aspnet/signalr` like this:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('/hubs/global', {
    accessTokenFactory: () => getToken()
  })
  .build()

connnection.on('some event', function doSomeThing() {})

connection
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log('start success'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

I want proxy the websocket connection to my server, so I have configured my `webpack.config.js` like this:

```
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: `http://${devServerIp}`,
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
  '/hubs': {
    target: `http://${devServerIp}`,
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
  },
},
```

But I got the follow error:
[Invalid frame header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8afp.png)

[image]

I want the dev-server can proxy the websocket request correctly.

Do you have some similar experience to solve this problem?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am running into something similar

Answer (score -1):

You should probable change HTTP to HTTPS.